# How to add recipient name to HTML email

Tags: asp.net, html-email, email

Our software sends HTML formatted transactional email to our users. While doing research I have found that it can be beneficial to include the recipients name as well as the email in the "To" field, we currently only populate the email. Example: To: John Doe

What is the correct method for implementing the recipient name in an email like this? Is it done at the code level of the email itself or somewhere else on the .NET server/config?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the `MailMessage` class, you can specify the name in the `MailAddress` constructor.

```
var mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("example@example.com", "John Doe"));
```